Using ROI (R) to construct a portfolio with various constraints
I am trying to using ROI to construct a portfolio where I maximize the portfolio yield for a given duration. To cut some corners I did try the Chat GPT path but with no gains.
The code is:
opt_data <- data <- data.frame(
  Type = c("Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Private", "Private", "Private"),
  Sector = c("Cash", "Senior Bank", "Senior Bank", "Senior Bank", "ABS", "Senior Bank", "ABS", "ABS", "ABS"),
  IGNG = c("IG", "IG", "IG", "IG", "IG", "IG", "NG", "NG", "NG"),
  Rating = c("AAA", "AA", "AA", "A", "AA", "A", "AA", "A", "AA"),
  Duration = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5),
  Yield = c(0.035, 0.05, 0.051, 0.052, 0.052, 0.053, 0.053, 0.054, 0.054)
)

objective_function <- function(weights) {
  weighted_yield <- sum(weights * opt_data$Yield)
  return(-weighted_yield)  # We're maximizing yield, so we use negative yield
}


opt_model <- ROI::OP(
  objective = "max",
  objective_fun = objective_function,
  constraints = list(
    sum = c(1, "="),  # Total weight equals 1
    private_assets = c(sum(opt_data$Type == "Private"), "<=", 0.5),  # Private assets cannot exceed 50%
    duration = c(sum(opt_data$Duration), "<=", 3),  # Portfolio duration cannot exceed 3
    cash_and_bank = c(sum(opt_data$Sector %in% c("Cash", "Senior Bank")), ">=", 0.1),  # Sum of cash and senior bank debt cannot be less than 10%
    investment_grade = c(sum(opt_data$IGNG == "IG"), "<=", 0.6)  # Sum of investment grade assets cannot be more than 60%
  ),
  types = "C"  # Continuous decision variables
)

# Solve optimization problem
opt_solution <- ROI::ROI_solve(opt_model, solver = "glpk")

# Extract the optimized weights
optimized_weights <- opt_solution$weights

# Print solution
print(opt_solution)


By way of explaination, the code is trying to maximize the portfolio yield  (which will be the sum of the weighted yield of each asset) while ensuring that :

the percentage of private assets does not exceed 50%
the portfolio duration is 3 (this again will be the sum of the weighted duration of each asset)
cash and bank must be at least 10%, and
Investment grade (IG) assets cannot be more than 60%

currently I get this error
Error in ROI::OP(objective = "max", objective_fun = objective_function,  : 
  unused argument (objective_fun = objective_function)


However, I am pretty sure there are other issues. For instance the duration of 3 has to be the weighted duration. Also, there is no vector in the dataframe for the weights.
If any can help I would appreciate it.

According to ?ROI::OP(), the function accepts the following arguments: OP(objective, constraints, types, bounds, maximum = FALSE). Your error is quite clear: There is no argument objective_fun . Classic-ChatGPT, making up approaches.
